# Using Dojo 1.9 how do you check if an element is visible?

Tags: dojo, hidden, visible

I hide or show a field with the following code:

Show element:

```
style.set(dojo.byId('fTypeId'), 'display', 'block');
```

Hide element:

```
style.set(dojo.byId('fTypeId'), 'display', 'none');
```

How can I test if this element is showing?

Comment: You've accepted answer that is technically **wrong**. See the Igor's answer. I'm downvoting the question because picking up wrong answer will mislead people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
require(["dojo/dom-style"], function(domStyle){
    var isVisible = (domStyle.get("yourNodeId", "display") !== "none");
});
```

Comment: This answer is simply **wrong!** It's very naive to check if given element has display == none. There are hundreds of cases where the element may be invisible, the simplest one where the parent is not visible. This answer being accepted misleads visitors.

Comment: I agree. Sorry for the misleading answer. Visitors please check the most upvoted one instead.

Answer (score 16):

The problem with the approach with checking `style['display']` is that your element may still be hidden, even though it's 'display' property is not set to 'none'. For instance, 'visibility' could be 'hidden', 'height' could be '0', the element could be obscured by another element and so on. In my experience it is more reliable to check for the element's height, rather than display. For example:

```
var isVisible = document.getElementById("myElem").offsetHeight != 0;
```

This test has the added benefit that it doesn't rely on any framework...

Comment: This is indeed a better solution, but you should also check for `offsetWidth` as well, because if an element has no width, it's not visible either. That's the same thing jQuery does for the `:visible` and `:hidden` selectors (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/hiddenVisibleSelectors.js). But please note that, unlike you mentioned in your answer, it will still be visible when `visibilty: hidden` or `opacity: 0` because they still keep their width/height!